Send JS function to Webview JS from Flutter
I have below function to return some data to JS side and It's a Map (However the flutter_inappwebview encodes the map after I return It), I do this by addJavaScriptHandler of flutter_inappwebview, But when I return the data I expect the returned object's readValue property is a function but It's not and in JS side the property type is string and I have to use eval of JS to convert this property to function and then use It.
return {
  // Other properties 
  'readValue': '''(async function() {
    var response = await window.myyApp.callHandler('eventName', { 'this': '$uuid' });
    return response;
  })
  ''',
};
}

I am looking for a way to return function in the first place.

Hey I'm still confused of what you're trying to do here, could you try explaining it in a different way?

@Amy
I am trying to return a JS object from flutter_inappwebview's addJavaScriptHandler function, But one property of that object is a function, But on JS side when the object is parse is not a function and It's a string and I need to run eval on JS side to make It a function.
